# Numbers appear before content CSS in RTL

Tags: css, list, numbers, arabic

I am Designing a Custom unordered list using the following :

```
.list-light li a:before {
content: "\f104";
font-family: FontAwesome;
margin-left: 8px;
color: #bcc987;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

it works just fine if the anchor starts with a character. but if I start it with a number i.e. 200 the bullet shifts.

how can I solve this issue?
[check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFynX.png)

the HTML CODE

```
<ul class="list-light">
<li><a href="/Portal/ND/515">تنفيذ أولى مراحل التحول الرقمي بمراكز استقبال ضيوف الرحمن بالمدينة المنورة</a></li>
<li><a href="/Portal/ND/514">أمير المدينة المنورة يرأس الاجتماع الأول لمجلس هيئة تطوير المنطقة</a></li>
<li><a href="/Portal/ND/513">خادم الحرمين الشريفين يصل إلى نيوم</a></li>
<li><a href="/Portal/ND/511"> أمير منطقة المدينة المنورة يرأس لجنة الحج بالمدينة المنورة</a></li>
<li><a href="/Portal/ND/510">200 ألف سائح يقلهم باص المدينة السياحي في عامه الأول</a></li>
```

Comment: Please share the relevant html code too

Comment: The relative HTML code was Added
@KK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `float:right`

CSS:

```
.list-light li a:before {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  margin-left: 8px;
  color: #bcc987;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
}

.list-light {
  direction: rtl;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/4914/